# How to create a slider using react components?

Tags: reactjs, slider, frontend, styled-components

I'm creating a slider but instead of being an `image slider` it should be a `components slider`.
**The issue is that only the child(slide) selected will be rendered**

I've looked at some tools like `Flicking` and `Slick`, both great by the way, the problem is that seems like is needed to have all the elements present in the DOM.

To put some code on the table I've the following:

```js
<Container>
  <SliderOne />
  <SliderTwo />
  <SliderThree />
</Container>
```

The container component is returning this:

```js
return (
      <div>
        <SliderScreen>{children[selected]}</SliderScreen>
      </div>
    );
```

When `selected` change using an on click handler

I want to show the slider motion effect when each slider changes, but I'm not sure if that is possible or always is needed to have rendered all the components even if there are not visible for the user.

Currently is changing correctly but without any motion.

Thank you!!

Comment: Does it have to be motion animation? This could be a bit difficult to implement. Could it be opacity animation?

Comment: Yeah, the requirement is with motion like a normal slider [1, 2, 3] left to right and viceversa depending if going back or next.

Comment: I understand. I can solve it with opacity animation easily.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.react-spring.io - here's an example... https://codesandbox.io/s/red-thunder-dtghq

Comment: Seem interesting @SakoBu thanks, let me check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3rd party library called [react-alice-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alice-carousel).

It renders gallery items as components.

[image: movement.gif]

Comment: Thanks for answering
Just that I think that `Alice Crousel`
Use something like this

```
<AliceCarousel mouseDragEnabled >
      <img src="/img2" onDragStart={handleOnDragStart} className="yours-custom-class" />
      <img src="/img5" onDragStart={handleOnDragStart} className="yours-custom-class" />
    </AliceCarousel>
```

And all the elements are present in the DOM, not renderer when are on the visual field of the user

Comment: Ah I see, You are looking for something SEO and Server Render capable, take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel then.